# Change NGINX configuration to look for relative paths

Tags: javascript, nginx

I was wondering how I could get NGINX to look for files that are essentially out of the root value. This is how my nginx.conf looks like within server

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
        root   /home/parallels/Downloads/nginx/rickshaw/examples;



location /all {
    alias /home/parallels/Downloads/nginx/rickshaw/examples
    try_files $uri $uri/ /sample.html /sample.htm;
    }


    #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
 }
```

I have a HTML file in rickshaw/examples that is calling on a javascript file that is located in `/home/parallels/Downloads/nginx/rickshaw/javascript/charts.js` by going like `src="../javascript/charts.js`. I tried using alias but that didn't really help. Any idea on how I could change the configuration file so that it can pick up on a file in a different relative directory. I know I could just copy the file into the root path but I want to find out how I can configure NGINX so that it looks for relative paths.

Thank you, and let me know if you need any further information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a static path

```
    location /javascript/ {
            alias /home/parallels/Downloads/nginx/rickshaw/javascript/;
            autoindex off;
    }
```

and access it `src="/javascript/charts.js"`